# Prevent google overlay/infowindow from allowing clicks through to markers underneath

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-styling

I'm trying to make some custom Google maps info windows, but I'm getting the issue where markers underneath my custom info window is clickable *through* the info window.

Here's an example ([basically straight from googles example here](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infowindow_custom/infowindow-custom.html))

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Info Window Custom</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

/* An InfoBox is like an info window, but it displays
 * under the marker, opens quicker, and has flexible styling.
 * @param {GLatLng} latlng Point to place bar at
 * @param {Map} map The map on which to display this InfoBox.
 * @param {Object} opts Passes configuration options - content,
 *   offsetVertical, offsetHorizontal, className, height, width
 */
function InfoBox(opts) {
  google.maps.OverlayView.call(this);
  this.latlng_ = opts.latlng;
  this.map_ = opts.map;
  this.offsetVertical_ = -195;
  this.offsetHorizontal_ = 0;
  this.height_ = 165;
  this.width_ = 266;

  var me = this;
  this.boundsChangedListener_ =
    google.maps.event.addListener(this.map_, "bounds_changed", function() {
      return me.panMap.apply(me);
    });

  // Once the properties of this OverlayView are initialized, set its map so
  // that we can display it.  This will trigger calls to panes_changed and
  // draw.
  this.setMap(this.map_);
}

/* InfoBox extends GOverlay class from the Google Maps API
 */
InfoBox.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();

/* Creates the DIV representing this InfoBox
 */
InfoBox.prototype.remove = function() {
  if (this.div_) {
    this.div_.parentNode.removeChild(this.div_);
    this.div_ = null;
  }
};

/* Redraw the Bar based on the current projection and zoom level
 */
InfoBox.prototype.draw = function() {
  // Creates the element if it doesn't exist already.
  this.createElement();
  if (!this.div_) return;

  // Calculate the DIV coordinates of two opposite corners of our bounds to
  // get the size and position of our Bar
  var pixPosition = this.getProjection().fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.latlng_);
  if (!pixPosition) return;

  // Now position our DIV based on the DIV coordinates of our bounds
  this.div_.style.width = this.width_ + "px";
  this.div_.style.left = (pixPosition.x + this.offsetHorizontal_) + "px";
  this.div_.style.height = this.height_ + "px";
  this.div_.style.top = (pixPosition.y + this.offsetVertical_) + "px";
  this.div_.style.display = 'block';
};

/* Creates the DIV representing this InfoBox in the floatPane.  If the panes
 * object, retrieved by calling getPanes, is null, remove the element from the
 * DOM.  If the div exists, but its parent is not the floatPane, move the div
 * to the new pane.
 * Called from within draw.  Alternatively, this can be called specifically on
 * a panes_changed event.
 */
InfoBox.prototype.createElement = function() {
  var panes = this.getPanes();
  var div = this.div_;
  if (!div) {
    // This does not handle changing panes.  You can set the map to be null and
    // then reset the map to move the div.
    div = this.div_ = document.createElement("div");
    div.style.border = "0px none";
    div.style.position = "absolute";
    div.style.background = "url('http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/images/blueinfowindow.gif')";
    div.style.width = this.width_ + "px";
    div.style.height = this.height_ + "px";
    var contentDiv = document.createElement("div");
    contentDiv.style.padding = "30px"
    contentDiv.innerHTML = "<b>Hello World!</b>";

    var topDiv = document.createElement("div");
    topDiv.style.textAlign = "right";
    var closeImg = document.createElement("img");
    closeImg.style.width = "32px";
    closeImg.style.height = "32px";
    closeImg.style.cursor = "pointer";
    closeImg.src = "http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/images/closebigger.gif";
    topDiv.appendChild(closeImg);

    function removeInfoBox(ib) {
      return function() {
        ib.setMap(null);
      };
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(closeImg, 'click', removeInfoBox(this));

    div.appendChild(topDiv);
    div.appendChild(contentDiv);
    div.style.display = 'none';
    panes.floatPane.appendChild(div);
    this.panMap();
  } else if (div.parentNode != panes.floatPane) {
    // The panes have changed.  Move the div.
    div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
    panes.floatPane.appendChild(div);
  } else {
    // The panes have not changed, so no need to create or move the div.
  }
}

/* Pan the map to fit the InfoBox.
 */
InfoBox.prototype.panMap = function() {
};

function initialize() {
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 8,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.397, 150.644),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      sensor: 'true'
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(-34, 150),
        map: map
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(e) {
      var infoBox = new InfoBox({latlng: marker.getPosition(), map: map});
    });

    var m2 = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.5, 150.5),
        map: map
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(m2, "click", function(e) {
      var infoBox = new InfoBox({latlng: m2.getPosition(), map: map});
    });

  }
</script>
</head>
<body style="margin:0px; padding:0px;" onload="initialize()">
  <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

You can see I'm making two markers, one just to the north east of the other. Click the bottom one then observe how the other marker is clickable through the marker (right near the 'W').

How can I fix this?! I've tried altering the z-index but that didn't seem to help.

This is using api v3 btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For posterity, you want to disable a bunch of events on the marker pop-up dom, this was the prescribed method, even though it feels like overkill. You could alternatively cycle through all the markers present apart from the one clicked and disable clicking on them (actually that's probably a better solution in hindsight). Depends on how many markers you have perhaps, I had *a lot*.

Something *like* this (transcribed here without testing from my coffeescript so...)

```
// All in a google.maps.OverlayView subclass.

...
this.listeners = new Array(); // save listeners for unbinding later
...
this.cancelEvents = function(){
    events = ['mousedown', 'mousemove', 'mouseover', 
            'mouseout', 'mouseup', 'mousewheel', 
            'DOMMouseScroll', 'touchstart', 'touchend', 
            'touchmove', 'dblclick', 'contextmenu'];
    // Note, don't disable 'click' if you want to be able to click links in the dom. Some things we're disabling here will can effect how your user might interact with the popup (double click to select text etc)
    for(var i = 0; i < events.length; i++){
        var event = events[i];
        this.listeners.push(
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(
                this.popup_dom_element,
                event,
                function(ev){
                    e.cancelBubble = true;
                    if(e.stopPropagation){
                        e.stopPropagation();
                    }
                }
            );
        );
    }
}

this.onAdd = function (){
    // build your html popup
    var html_code = "...";
    // easy way to get a dom element but probably over kill if its your only JQ
    this.popup_dom_element = $(html_code);
    this.cancelEvents();
}

this.onRemove = function(){
    // any other removal code you have
    ...
    for(var i = 0; i < this.listeners.length; i++){
        // remove our event listeners
        google.maps.event.removeListener(this.listeners[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try and use the MapPane `overlayMouseTarget` instead of `floatPane`.

Comment: Looking at the other answers, i feel like yours is the only one which understands and solves and the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want people to be able to click on a marker, could you call `marker.setClickable(false)`

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem and its actually very easy:/

if u are using jquery just set

```
$(div).bind("click",function(e) {
 return false;
});
```

in the InfoBox.prototype.createElement function. This should help.

Cheers

Comment: I wanted a non-jq solution (I don't use jQuery in my code, just in the given sample). Also you might want to stop stop mouse scrolls too, else your map will zoom when you try to scroll an info boxes content. Maps 3.7 should have fixed this issue: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/wiki/JavascriptMapsAPIv3Changelog http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3573

Answer (score 0):

use:

google.maps.event.addDomListener

instead of

google.maps.event.addListener

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. When answering questions please try to provide more information to help explain your answer to the person that posted the question.

Comment: The once perhaps useful information is not advisable anymore, `google.maps.event.addDomListeners` is deprecated in google maps and will be removed.